# GatsbyJS: Import npm package in serviceworker file (gatsby-plugin-offline)

Tags: javascript, npm, import, service-worker

We use gatsby-plugin-offline in order to get a auto-generated service worker. It works fine since all pages are available offline now. With the following code in gatsby-config.js, some additional code can be added to the service worker.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  options: {
    appendScript: 'src/custom-sw-code.js',
  },
},
```

Within custom-sw-code.js we could not manage to import any npm package so far. If we use `import` or `require` on top of the file, browsers complain about non-working serviceworker code (after building and serving the app).

Do you know, how to import packages in the serviceworker?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull in external scripts into a service worker, [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) will help. (Another option is to use [static ES module imports](https://web.dev/es-modules-in-sw/), but they aren't supported in all browsers as of this writing.)

For each script URL you pass in, `importScripts()` will synchronously download and execute the code within the context of the current [`ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope). The service worker will also take care of automatically caching the scripts, so you don't need to manually add those URLs to a cache, and the request for those scripts won't trigger your service worker's `fetch` event listeners.

If you're loading code from `npm` from a CDN, make sure that you're requesting either a [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) or [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) bundle, and make note of what the exported global symbols are, as that's what will end up being exposed in the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`.